# How to align CheckBox to the top of its description in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-xml

I would like to align `CheckBox` "symbol" to the top of its description.

What I have now:
[image: before]

What I want to have:
[image: after]

Current xml:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/register_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/register_hint"/>
```

I've tried to achieve this by manipulating `layout_gravity` attributes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe is not elegant, but putting a checkbox without text and then a textview besides it may do what you want.  As I don't know a way for doing what you want natively.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`android:gravity="top"` will fix the problem:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/register_checkbox"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/register_hint"
          android:gravity="top"/>
```

Note that `android:gravity` is different than `android:layout_gravity`.

Comment: Your solution works! In fact I was manipulating `android:layout_gravity` attributes, so this is why I couldn't see any effects.

Comment: Why mine did not work ? I had to use a CheckBox on the left and a TextView on the right .

Comment: This won't work fine on some language like CJK

Comment: This solution kinda half works. The text gets weirdly aligned with the checkbox. To handle that `padding_top="4dp"` is needed as mentioned by Abdul Rashid.

Answer (score 25):

- use

  > android:gravity="top"
  >   it will pin the box on top
- use

  > padding_top="4dp"
  >   will adjust Text padding only (without changing box padding from top)

Comment: Adding `padding_top` solves issue with ugly cuts on top of text. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I found that:

```
 android:gravity="fill"
```

works better than "top". Top wouldn't look right if the checkbox may also end up as only one line.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution in fact! It works equally well for short (one-line) texts and long texts, and without resorting to making assumptions about the font size with a static padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="2dp">
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/checkbox" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="2dp">
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/checkboxselected" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="2dp">
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/checkbox" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: If you have vector drawable use <item android:top="2dp" android:drawable="..."/> instead of <item><bitmap android:src="..."/></item>