# Checkbox with multiline text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I want to align `checkbox` at top with two line text. I want **Checkbox and text in the same line at top**

**Note : I have tried `android:gravity="top"` but getting some extra padding inside text of checkbox.**

I have tried : [How to align CheckBox to the top of its description in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34660323/8089770) but it didn't worked.

I have tried :

```
<CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/chkConfirmSymbol"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox_black"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:gravity="top"
     android:paddingTop="0dp"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
     android:text="@string/at_least_1_symbol"
     android:textColor="@drawable/selector_checkbox_text_black"
     android:textSize="@dimen/font_11" />
```

Output :

[image]

As per the image above i am getting some padding in the text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Checkbox and text in the same line at top. you can see checkbox is too high right now :(

Comment: @Annie could you please add it to your question, as for now, it doesn't specify "Checkbox and text in the same line at top."

Comment: you are limiting the edit text width by using these lines `android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_weight="1"`  so in this current width the text will grow in height and the checkbox circle will be on the top.

Comment: @fatemehfallahiarezoudar even after removing weight and width it is showing same output

Comment: use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:maxLines="1"`

Comment: I would recommend making a compound control :) Then you have much more control.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do it simple way? why you needed `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`?

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="At least 1 symbol(!@#$%^&*)"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Or you can have look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637608/2289835) it should help you.

Comment: Note: this won't work as required if a user changes his *Font size* in accessibility settings

Comment: For that, have a look at [This answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637608/2289835)

Comment: this one totally ignores user preferences. 
android:textSize="13dp".

Comment: maybe try building your button using sp instead of dp will help (not sure have't tried)

Answer (score 2):

You can find default drawable file used for checkbox in `sdk > platforms > API_VERSION > data > res > drawable`

If you check any of resource image used with default drawable, for eg `btn_check_off` used in this drawable you can see that the **default image is having some default padding** in image itself. And the custom image that you are using is missing it. Add default padding to your image resource and it should work fine.

See below image for reference. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have just managed it by giving some `android:paddingTop`, you can also try to do it in the same way.

**XML Code (for layout):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:text="@string/at_least_1_symbol"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically how you do it:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minLines="2"
```

This would still get scaled into a single line on tablet (landscape) screens.